# Explicit loading for computed property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose that in my model I have a computed property `A` that depends on `B` and `C.D`.

Is it possible to make

```
.Include("A")
```

be equal to

```
.Include("B").Include("C.D")
```

in my linq to entity expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifies related objects to include in the query results (i.e. tables to join). Thus `A` is not a related object, but a simple computed property, then it's not possible to include it.

---

Inspired by @CodeCaster - if you don't want to create repository for this entity, you can write extension method which will do the including

```
public static IQueryable<Foo> IncludeA(this DbSet<Foo> foos)
{
    return foos.Include("B").Include("C.D");
}
```

Usage:

```
db.Foos.IncludeA()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with Entity Framework by default, but if you wrap your actual entity (say, `X`) in some sort of Entity Framework-specific repository that executes `Include()`s according to the situation, you could end up with something like this:

```
public class XRepository
{
    private IDbSet<X> _dbSet;

    public IQueryable<X> Include()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }

    public IQueryable<X> IncludeForA()
    {
        return Include().Include("B")
                        .Include("C.D")
    }
}
```

Then from wherever you want to access a collection of `X` with `B` and `C.D` included, call the `IncludeForA()` method.

Comment: @Sergey that was not my intention, why do you think so? Note the entity this set returns is `X`, where a relation of `X.A` is assumed (and `X.B` and `X.C.D`).

Comment: I think so because `A` is not a navigation property